# signInSuccessWithAuthResult return value in Firebase UI callbacks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, config, firebaseui

When I sign in with firebase UI, it gives an error saying this:

> No redirect URL has been found. You must either specify a signInSuccessUrl in the configuration, pass in a redirect URL to the widget URL, or return false from the callback.

That explains why it would work when I pass a `signinSuccesfulURL`, but I did return false from my callbacks! But since I am using typescript, it actually return a `Promise<boolean>`. I don't know if that is related to my error.

But I don't want to use `signinSuccesfulURL` because I don't want it to redirect, I want it to stay on the current page after signing in successfully.

```
//firebaseui component
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth"
import firebase from "gatsby-plugin-firebase"
import React from "react"

const firebaseFunctions = firebase.functions()


const firebaseuipage = dataToSubmit => {
  console.log("within firebase ui", dataToSubmit)
  var uiConfig = {
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    //   {
    //     provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    //     buttonColor: "#3A3A51",
    //   },
      {
        provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        fullLabel: "Create Custom Account",
        buttonColor: "#ED6A5A",
      },
    ],

    tosUrl: "<your-tos-url>",
    privacyPolicyUrl: function () {
      window.location.assign("<your-privacy-policy-url>")
    },
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async(authResult) => {
        const someFunction = firebaseFunctions.httpsCallable("some_function");       
        try {
           let result = await  someFunction(dataToSubmit)
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("within firebase service:", error)
        }
        console.log(authResult)
        return false
      },
    },
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={(uiConfig as any)} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default firebaseuipage
```

```
//error
// I actually fixed this by passing uiConfig={(uiConfig as any)} in the above component 
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<Props>): StyledFirebaseAuth', gave the following error.
    Type '{ signInOptions: (string | { provider: string; fullLabel: string; buttonColor: string; })[]; tosUrl: string; privacyPolicyUrl: () => void; callbacks: { signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (authResult: any) => Promise<...>; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Config'.
      The types returned by 'callbacks.signInSuccessWithAuthResult(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context?: any): StyledFirebaseAuth', gave the following error.
    Type '{ signInOptions: (string | { provider: string; fullLabel: string; buttonColor: string; })[]; tosUrl: string; privacyPolicyUrl: () => void; callbacks: { signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (authResult: any) => Promise<...>; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Config'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(5, 3): The expected type comes from property 'uiConfig' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<StyledFirebaseAuth> & Readonly<Props> & Readonly<...>'
index.d.ts(5, 3): The expected type comes from property 'uiConfig' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<StyledFirebaseAuth> & Readonly<Props> & Readonly<...>'
```

Comment: It looks like FirebaseUI is considering a redirect flow, while you want it to use its popup flow. What happens if you explicitly [configure](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configuration) `signInFlow: "popup"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling this won't work:

```
signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async(authResult) => {
  const someFunction = firebaseFunctions.httpsCallable("some_function");       
  try {
     let result = await  someFunction(dataToSubmit)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("within firebase service:", error)
  }
  console.log(authResult)
  return false
},
```

Since you marked the function as `async` it returns a promise, not a simple `true` or `false` value that FirebaseUI expects.

You **may** be able to get away with not marking the callback as `async` and simply returning false, although you'll have no way to synchronize FirebaseUI's operation to your Cloud Function call in that case.

Comment: You are totally right Frank! That's the problem about the `Promise<boolean>` value doesn't match the exact boolean type that Firebase UI asks for.

Comment: For whoever might encounter this problem later, change async/await to `then` solution to handle the promise

Comment: @Yingqi Can you give an example of using the `.then` solution?